# Find All groups that a group is a member of recursively and show as a tree

Tags: c#, active-directory

Using the method [GetGroups()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.groupprincipal.getgroups(v=vs.110).aspx) finds the groups that my group is a member of. But I have to look into each memberOf of all groups that I got by doing `GetGroups()` until there is no parent anymore, so I can have a tree structure like below.

Example:

`MyGroup` is the group I'm searching for.

I need output something like this:

```
>     ParentGroup
>     ---ChildGroup
>     ------MyGroup
> 
>     AnotherParentGroup
>     ---AnotherChildGroup
>     ------AnotherChildChildGroup
>     ---------MyGroup
```

This happens when `MyGroup` is member of multiple groups. Then I have to look for each Group and also to the Groups it is a member of until I reach the root groups. This can lead to more than one tree as you can see above.

Can someone help with writing a pseudo-code or can someone give me some advice about what method to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This console app does what you want, chop and change it however you need:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
        using (var user = UserPrincipal.Current)
        using (var userGroups = user.GetGroups())
        {
            PrintGroups(userGroups, 0);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void PrintGroups(PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> groups, int level)
    {
        foreach (var group in groups)
        {
            Console.Write(new string('-', level * 3));
            Console.WriteLine(group.Name);
            using (var groupGroups = group.GetGroups())
            {
                PrintGroups(groupGroups, level + 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```